# Ember.js deprecation of registerImplementation in favour of App.initializer

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using an extension of HashLocation to implement a hashbang url type for Ember.js.

Here is the code snippet:

```
(function() {

var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set;

Ember.Location.registerImplementation('hashbang', Ember.HashLocation.extend({ 

    getURL: function() {
        return get(this, 'location').hash.substr(2);
    },

    setURL: function(path) {
        get(this, 'location').hash = "!"+path;
        set(this, 'lastSetURL', "!"+path);
    },

    onUpdateURL: function(callback) {
        var self = this;
        var guid = Ember.guidFor(this);

            Ember.$(window).bind('hashchange.ember-location-'+guid, function() {
                Ember.run(function() {
                    var path = location.hash.substr(2);
                    if (get(self, 'lastSetURL') === path) { return; }

                    set(self, 'lastSetURL', null);

                    callback(location.hash.substr(2));
                });
            });
        },

        formatURL: function(url) {
            return '#!'+url;
        }

    }));

})();
```

I use this by reopening the Router:

```
App.Router.reopen({
    location: 'hashbang'
});
```

However, on running the application, i'm hitting the following deprecation:

```
DEPRECATION: Using the Ember.Location.registerImplementation is no longer supported. Register your custom location implementation with the container instead.
```

I can't find any information on how to do this.  Does anyone have any implementation snippets on what I would have to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to deprecation message. use container instead.

```
(function() {

var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set;

var hashbangLocation = Ember.HashLocation.extend({ 

    getURL: function() {
        return get(this, 'location').hash.substr(2);
    },

    setURL: function(path) {
        get(this, 'location').hash = "!"+path;
        set(this, 'lastSetURL', "!"+path);
    },

    onUpdateURL: function(callback) {
        var self = this;
        var guid = Ember.guidFor(this);

            Ember.$(window).bind('hashchange.ember-location-'+guid, function() {
                Ember.run(function() {
                    var path = location.hash.substr(2);
                    if (get(self, 'lastSetURL') === path) { return; }

                    set(self, 'lastSetURL', null);

                    callback(location.hash.substr(2));
                });
            });
        },

        formatURL: function(url) {
            return '#!'+url;
        }

    });

App.register('location:hashbang', hashbangLocation);

})();
```

Reopen it as usual

```
App.Router.reopen({
    location: 'hashbang'
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was after.  Thanks!

Comment: This registers the implementation on the application, not on the container as the deprecation message suggests. Are those the same thing?