# Ember.js: App.register undefined in app.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I got a deprecation message when running my app: `DEPRECATION: Using the Ember.Location.registerImplementation is no longer supported. Register your custom location implementation with the container instead.`. The code is in the app.js.

It is for the hashbang functionality, and I saw someone already written a nice implementation for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23055007/1153884

So I literally copied and pasted that code. But after fiddling I could not get it to work. It is because App.register trows an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
[image]

I have also tested with `App.__container__.register`. However that does also not work. Is there something changed with the latest Ember CLI that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember CLI doesn’t use `App` as a global namespace, it uses ES6 modules.

You can create a new initializer in `app/initialzers`:

```
export default {
  name: 'hashbang',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

The initializer is passed the container as a parameter.